# Is there a way to add spec/features to rails scaffold generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

Using rspec, I would like the app to stop generating request specs and start generating feature specs instead. spec/features are used by capybara.  The request spec generator could be omitted with

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework  :rspec, :request_specs => false
end
```

Is there a setting to enable feature specs when generating scaffolds?

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure you have upgraded to the newest rspec-rails, just in case this is available there. If that doesn't help, you can always [add your own generator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html).